# ssh continually hangs on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ssh, lts

After typing a few commands my new install of Ubuntu 16.04 hangs. Sometimes it will come back to life after a few seconds (30 or so) other times it just crashes.

I have over 14 servers running previous version of Ubuntu LTS but the new load with 16.04 crashes continuously. I am using Konsole as a client from another machine on the local network.

I can login to any of the previous release with no problem.

Any thoughts or known bug fixes ?

Comment: can you post the crash messages please

Comment: There is no crash. But I am now convinced there is a conflict issue with ssh on 16.04.  The client was 16.04 desktop sshing to 16.04 LTS. I reloaded the server with 14.05 LTS and there is no problem.

I have run memtest with no errors.
<br/>
CONFIG SETTINGS:

Host        tgideon
HostName    192.168.0.185
Port 1200
User        jmd
TCPKeepAlive    yes
ServerAliveInterval     5
ServerAliveCountMax     30

Comment: debug3: receive packet: type 82
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 82
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 82
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 82
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 82
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 82

Comment: thats just normal use.

Answer (score 1):

It could be an intermittent hardware issue on your new server.  Faulty cable? NIC? Was this machine previously OK running 14.04 ?

Since you are able to connect fine to other machines, if the problem is not hardware, perhaps you should have a look at the configuration of the ssh daemon on the the new 16.04 box,  `vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

What have you tried already to troubleshoot this ?
You can run sshd with debugging options on the 16.04 box:
     " ...debug mode provides a lot of information about the connection and a smaller amount about the server configuration. The server's debugging level (-**d**) can be raised once, twice (-**dd**) or thrice (-**ddd**). "

On your terminal, you can run the ssh client with -vvv option as well.

```
ssh -p 22 -vvv <user>@<server>
```

Comment: I can connect fine to the 16.04 machine, it is after the connection is established for a few minutes and a few commands that ssh hangs.